# multi-tasking or multitasking?

Tags: grammar

May I ask weather or not to use a hyphen after a prefix only depends on individuals' editorial style, but not that of British or American English?

E.g., multi-tasking or multitasking?

Many thanks!

Comment: Speaking as a programmer for over 40 years, whichever gets the task done.

Comment: What is your grammar question? Grammar covers syntax and morphology. Orthography covers capitalization, spelling, and punctuation; it has nothing to do with grammar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When deciding if hyphenation is appropriate, I would consider what the audience is accustomed to seeing, and whehter or not the hyphen in question would help overall understanding.

Rule: Use the hyphen with the prefix re only when re means again AND omitting the hyphen would cause confusion with another word.

Example: Will she recover from her illness?
Re does not mean again so no hyphen.

Example: I have re-covered the sofa twice. 
Re does mean again AND omitting the hyphen would have caused confusion with another word so hyphenate.

Example: The stamps have been reissued. 
Re means again but would not cause confusion with another word so no hyphen.

Example: I must re-press the shirt. 
Re means again AND omitting the hyphen would cause confusion with another word so hyphenate.

Of course, some writers incorporate hyphens as part of their personal writing style, which could be the case in the example you cited (multi-tasking vs multitasking).

Comment: Rule: An ELU stipulation is that quotes should be identified as such, and a link given. But there is a legal requirement (to avoid copyright legislation) that quotes must be correctly attributed. // Disambiguation is hardly relevant in OP's example. Readability is a more salient factor in this case. But this has all been covered before on ELU.